# Transform a JsonArray into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

***I have this json that i got using the YoutubeAPI :***

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "ob1ogBV9_iE"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "13 estrellas ",
    "description": "Pueden encontrar estas "
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "o9vsXyrola4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Rayos Cósmicos ",
    "description": "Este es un programa piloto "
   }
  }
]
}
```

***i want to save the fiel "id" on an ArrayList but i have some problems this is the code im using:***

```
JSONArray jsonArray = myResponse.getJSONArray("items");
```

***In this line im creating an JSONarray with the JSONobject i created first***

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        list.add(json.getString("videoID"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***My question is how can i access to this field? and how can i save it***

Comment: the videoId is a subProperty of an object called id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two main issues.  The first is that `"videoID"` and `"videoId"` are not the same string.  So you're checking for a key that doesn't exist.

Your second problem is that the `"videoId"` key doesn't exist in the top level object, it's inside the `"id"` object, so you need to drill down an extra layer to get it:

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = myResponse.getJSONArray("items");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject id = json.getJSONObject("id");

            list.add(id.getString("videoId"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list);  // [ob1ogBV9_iE, o9vsXyrola4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with correct case for `videoId`, like

```
list.add(json.getString("videoId"));
```